# layout with specific shape

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-api-3

I want to create an activity that in it user can view some statistics for each state, something like this:

state activity example

[image: state activity example]

Color of each state is based on statistics and when user clicks on each state another activity opens up. My problem is how to achieve this? I can create 50 fragments but how can I define specific shapes for each one (to resemble a map)? Seems like google map may have some API but i was not able to find any good reference.

Unfortunately i couldn't find a proper implementation for this problem, the best thing that i could come up with is something like this :

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.vira.as.testmap.MainActivity">

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/im1"
       android:layout_width="135dp"
       android:layout_height="320dp"
       android:src="@drawable/california"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/im2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="370dp"
        android:src="@drawable/nevada"
        android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/im1"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/im3"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arizona"
        android:layout_marginBottom="128dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/im2"
        android:layout_marginStart="88dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The result is this, which is obviously inefficient and a real pain but at least is working: 
[image: sample result]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define the shape of a fragment since it is a invisible, rectangular container for views. Maybe this is what you are looking for (see [1]: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes). Try to paint a polygonal area with transparency (`0 < α < 1`) in foreground of the map and handle the click events.